# How do I prime factorize large numbers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, prime-factoring

I'm trying to solve [Project Euler third question](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) but while my code works perfectly with small numbers when I try to use big number it doesn't give me any answer.

```
#include<iostream>

using std :: cout;
using std :: cin;
using std :: endl;

int main()
{
   long long int a = 0, bigPrime = 0, smallPrime = 2, prime = 0;
   cout << "Please enter a number...!" << endl;
   cin >> a;

   for(long long int i = 2 ; i < a ; i++)
   {
      for(long long int c = 2 ; c < i ; c++)
      {
         if(i % c != 0)
         {
            prime = i;
         }
         else
         {
            prime = 0;
            break;
         }
      }
      if(prime > 0 )
      {
         if(a % prime == 0)
         {
            bigPrime = prime;
         }
      }

  }


  cout << "The biggest prime is = " << bigPrime << endl;
  return 0;
```

}

That's my bad code :)
i am using ubuntu linux and g++
what is wrong with my code and how can i improve it?

Comment: In what range do your `small numbers` and `big numbers` lie?

Comment: What is an example of a number that doesn't work? I bet it's > (2^127)-1

Comment: for example 600851475143 this number doesnt work but if i use numbers like 1000 or 23613 it works perfectly

Comment: With the Euler case, your outer loop iterates over six hundred billion times, and most of the inner loops also billions of times. The Euler problems usually need you to use mathematics before you attempt a solution, and it is very rare that a brute-gorce approach will work.

Comment: i looked my program again and i saw that my code probably working but it's too slow like molbdnilo said (if there is grammar mistakes sorry for that)

Comment: so , mmm what can i do to be make faster my code?

Comment: thanks molbdnilo youre suggestion was pretty usefull i came to a point but after that point, I couldnt understand my code :) - i need more practice ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve your program using one simple trick:

Every time you find a divisor `d`, divide your number by `d`.

That means that for every divisor found, your number gets smaller, making the remaining part easier to factor.

As a bonus, that means you don't need to be so careful about only using primes as divisors. Every time a divisor is found, it's the smallest divisor of the current number, and since it's the smallest divisor, it must be a prime. That saves a whole level of looping.

The factors are extracted in order from smallest to highest, so in the end what you have is the highest prime factor - the answer to this challenge.

This is not a fast algorithm, but 600851475143 is not a large number and this algorithm will factor it no problem.

For examle ([on ideone](https://ideone.com/KlLz7q)):

```
for (long long int d = 2; d * d <= a; d++) {
    if (a % d == 0) {
        a /= d;
        d--; // this is to handle repeated factors
    }
}
```

I also used the old `d * d <= a` trick but you don't even need it here. It helps if the highest factor is high, and in this example it is not.

Comment: good answer. I would perhaps replace the if statement with a while statment to avoid the d-- part

Comment: Thx for your answer this is exactly what i want (and i am new here what a usefull platform :) )

Comment: I'd consider testing if `2` is a factor as a special case before the loop, then start testing at `d = 3` and add `2` at each step.   That simple tweak will (almost) halve the number of values checked.   There are also reasonably efficient means of calculating the "integer square root"  (i.e. the smallest integer that, when multiplied by itself exceeds `a`) - doing that calculation once will mean less work testing the loop condition, particularly for larger values.

Answer (score 0):

But the [problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) states that you just need to find the biggest prime of 600851475143, right? Why don't you just iterate from sqrt(600851475143) to 2 and return the first number that is a prime?

```
bool isPrime(uint64_t num)
{
  bool result = true;
  for(uint64_t i = 2; i < std::sqrt(num); ++i)
  {
    if(num % i == 0)
    {
      result = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  uint64_t num = 600851475143;
  uint64_t i = std::sqrt(num);
  while (i > 1)
  {
    i--;
    if (num%i != 0) continue;
    if (isPrime(i))
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

For sure it can be done faster, but it takes 10ms on my machine, so I guess it's not terrible.

Comment: Thanks man , for now i dont now anything about uint64_t decleration but i will google it

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef long long ulong;

int main()
{
ulong num = 600851475143;
ulong div = num;
ulong p = 0;

ulong i = 2;
while (i * i <= div)
{
    if (div % i == 0)
    {
        div /= i;
        p = i;
    }
    else {
        i++;
    }
}

if (div > p) 
{ 
    p = div;
}

cout << p << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: the insides of your while loop can be replaced with

while(div % i == 0)
    div /= i;
++i

Comment: Thx for answer, it was really helpfull for me